# Gerrit accepting pushes without change-id

Tags: git, gerrit

We have two git projects both using gerrit.

**Project 1**

- Set up a few years ago
- Works correctly with gerrit
- If a push does not include a Change-Id, gerrit rejects the submission

**Project 2**

- Set up a few weeks ago
- Does not work correctly with gerrit
- If a push does not include a Change-Id, gerrit still accepts the submission
- The submit is still placed in the approval queue, and, once approved, is properly merged.
- Rebases do not always work.  If the original push included a proper change-id, then a rebase and `commit --amend` will work.  If the original push did not include a proper change-id, then rebases or `commit --amend` results in a brand new change-id generated somewhere every time.

(A bit of background is that some designers forgot to install the commit hook.  Their pushes should have failed, but did not.)

If it makes a difference, Project 1 is not bare, Project 2 is bare.)

**Why (what is the setting) that would cause one project to (correctly) require Change-Ids, and another to not?**  I have not been able to find this in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the "Require Change-Id in commit message" option to TRUE in Project 2 (administration rights is required).

More info: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/project-configuration.html#require-change-id

Comment: Thank you.  That is exactly what I was looking for.  

For anyone else - this is available in the Gerrit UI under Projects / List and select your project.